# Dropbox Carousel API

Tags: rest, dropbox

Dropbox has recently launched a new photo viewing and album management app call [Carousel](https://carousel.dropbox.com).  I am looking for a way to access the albums through an API.  Specifically, get a list of all albums, and for a specific album, get a list of files.  I was looking through the [Dropbox API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers), but was unable to find any reference to this.  Is there anyway to do this currently or has the API just not been updated with this rather new functionality?

Answer (score 3):

The Dropbox API does not currently expose any Carousel or albums functionality, but we're tracking this as a feature request.